# Make function work during first hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('div').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('current');
    changeColor();
});
```

The first line adds class to a div called "current" and I also have a code that when the 'current' div is hovered, I want to change the color of the div using the changeColor function. But for some reason this code is not working during the first hover, but when i hover it the second time it works fine.

Comment: how is the other hover handler added

Comment: This doesn't add a class to a `div` called current. You mean it adds the class "current" to the `div`. Can you show your CSS and maybe some more code (the function)

Comment: plead provide http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lxhzamk3/1/

Answer (score 0):

why you need the changeColor()?

I've made this example http://jsfiddle.net/byb8Lb5w/4/

**Jquery:**

```
jQuery('div').hover(function(){
    jQuery('div.current').removeClass('current');
    jQuery(this).addClass('current');
});
```

**Css:**

```
div.current:hover{
    background-color:blue;
}
```